# « Il est persuadé qu'en cultivant des cailloux le temps sur son lit ricoche. »

Tags: sens

J’ai besoin d’un coup de main pour creuser cette phrase, tirée de la chanson *Planter des cailloux* de *Syrano*. Les paroles sont disponibles sur la toile. J’ai utilisé trois dictionnaires, mais je n’ai nulle part découvert comment je dois la comprendre.

> Il est persuadé qu'en cultivant des cailloux le temps sur son lit
>   ricoche.

Le seul mot que je ne connaissais pas était *ricocher*. Il me semble maintenant que « jeter une pierre aplatie sur l’eau tellement qu’elle y rebondit quelque fois » est l’acception la plus commune.

Je pense que quelque chose m’échappe quand je lis les mots « le temps sur son lit ricoche ». Je crois qu’il s’agit du langage figuré ici. Ma propre pensée, c’est que le sujet de la phrase essaie de ralentir le temps en espérant qu’il puisse se détendre ou dormir plus souvent. Il m’est aussi venu à l’esprit que le mot « ricocher » a peut-être quelque chose à voir avec les cailloux que le personnage de la chanson enfouit. À cet égard, ça peut être un calembour?

En tout cas, ma compréhension me semble fort douteuse. Pourriez-vous m’éclaircir ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ricocher* veut aussi dire qu'un objet (une balle de revolver par exemple) ne pénètre pas dans la cible, mais 'rebondit' en changeant de direction.

Le temps n'a plus de prise sur son lit, celui-ci devient un espace hors du temps ; c'est à dire qu'il ne vieillit pas, que le temps est arrêté lorsqu'il est dans son lit, et plus généralement que lui-même n'est plus concerné par le temps parce qu'il cultive des cailloux.

Cultiver des cailloux est un signe de la *folie douce* qui n'est pas dangereuse, mais on n'y récolte rien ; par les ricochets les cailloux passent d'une activité stérile à un conclusion évidemment fausse.

C'est une forme d'humour, de dérision poétique qui ironise sur les folies ordinaires, sur les dérangements que l'imagination entraîne sur les faibles d'esprit.

Answer (score -1):

I did not look at the context of the song; what comes to my mind when reading the sentence is:
Habituellement, c'est le caillou qui ricoche à la surface d'un fleuve (ou ruisseau), et qui est projeté un peu plus loin, dans la même direction.
Ici, c'est le temps (assimilé à un fleuve) qui ricoche sur les cailloux.